# How to set the path of a folder and be indepedent in every system?

Tags: vb.net, image, telerik, telerik-radbutton

I want to give image to a component. i give it successfuly with the full path `Me.RadButtonElement1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Project-2015\MusicStore\MusicStore\Resources\FilteredFolderClosed.png")` but i want this path be indepedent and look the Application.Startpath. i have tried this but from default the Application.Startpath gives **C:\Project-2015\MusicStore\MusicStore\bin\Debug** so i cant tell something like `Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath & "\Resources\FilteredFolderOpen.png")`

Comment: The `Resources` folder will not exist when you publish the application, so to be on the safe side you should place everything in the same directory as the .exe, which `Application.StartupPath` points you to. So in your case you could create a folder called Resources there: `C:\Project-2015\MusicStore\MusicStore\bin\Debug\Resources` and then do as you do above: `Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath & "\Resources\FilteredFolderOpen.png")`.

Comment: ok yes but programm has somehow the information from resources so maybe i dont need to create new resources folder

Comment: but this helps and is a correct answer thanks!!